# Standard attack vs full attack at low level

Tags: pathfinder-1e, combat, attack

At a low enough level that a character only has one BAB, is there any incentive to using a full attack, or is it more advantageous to hang on to the move action and use a standard attack?

Comment: A full attack only applies if more than one attack occurs, so for a character with only one attack, the full attack action doesn't apply or come into play.

Comment: @Wyrmwood Please answer in actual answers.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

## It matters for some characters

If you have, for example, Two-Weapon Fighting, Flurry of Blows, Rapid Shot, or *haste*, you may have more than one attack even though you have low BAB. You would need a Full-Attack to use those. Even with only one attack, some characters (e.g. a 3rd-level Swordlord Fighter) can get other benefits from making a Full Attack, and therefore may Full-Attack for just one attack, burning their Move action for the sake of that bonus.

But if you have only one attack and don't have any other special feature that references Full Attacks, there is no reason to choose to use one; you'd be burning your Move action for no reason.

Note that you do not choose between Attack and Full-Attack until after that first attack (assuming you still have a Move action to make the Full-Attack an option).

Comment: I don't think your description in the second paragraph is strictly accurate - I believe a character is able to declare a full attack, even if there is no benefit in doing so. The sequence you describe, of converting from a single attack to a Full Attack is optional.

Comment: @YogoZuno I'm reasonably sure. You definitely don't have to choose between an Attack and a Full Attack until after the first. I suppose extra attacks wouldn't be required if you had some other benefit, which implies that they aren't necessary in general...

Comment: yeah, that's what I was trying to get at. The 'escalation' to a Full from a Standard attack is correct, but I don't believe there is anything preventing going straight to Full Attack if there was some reason to.

Comment: One benefit that isn't an extra attack is that at level 3, the Swordlord archetype for Fighter gains +1 deflection during a full attack. I believe you would need to declare your full attack before the first (and only) roll if you provoked an attack, which would only happen if an enemy had a readied action. I can't think of any effects that increases attack rather than AC.

Comment: However, if you look to my answer the SRD says explicitly that the first attack is a standard action, and any following attacks convert to full attack.

Comment: @CatLord I don't think YogoZuno's arguing that point, I think he's saying that you can declare a Full-Attack after your first attack even if you have no more, for example to activate the deflection bonus Jon mentions. I'd certainly allow it, anyway, and I highly doubt that the Swordlord archetype was written with that power at level 3 imagining it wouldn't be useful until 6th.

Comment: The only time a single attack counts as a full attack is if you take a 5' step beforehand which means it is still usable, even though you can't dual wield.  This might have been an oversight by the writers because they were trying to use the level-based stacking (1 + [level-3] / 4)

Comment: @CatLord None of your comment is making sense to me. I don't see how whether or not making a 5-ft. Step matters here provided you still have your Move available, don't see why you can't dual wield, and don't see what that formula has to do with the fact that it's a 3rd-level feature that's unusable at 3rd-level as you have described things. Stupid/nonsensical things like that certainly *can* be part of RAW, but I'd have to see language explicitly stating that you cannot Full-Attack if you have only one attack.

Comment: Are you in the chat at all?  I have a few minutes to elaborate.  I'm truncating quite a bit for comment space.

Comment: "The following benefits only apply when a swordlord is using a dueling sword and carrying nothing in his other hand." is listed for the archetype which is why I say dual-wielding is out.  

"The only movement you can take during a full attack is a 5-foot step. You may take the step before, after, or between your attacks." so a player could say that their 5' step + attack is a full attack if they want, although the step is a free action so it's neither here nor there.  The AC bonus is +1 for every additional 4 levels, so getting it earlier means a higher bonus later.

Comment: Also this could be a contingent for a multi-classed character who might have two or more attacks by the time they take on the Swordlord archetype, so a lv3 swordlord can have a full attack.  Also the bonus reflects the Armor Training bonus in level and bonus and arguably a duelist won't be wearing heavy armor so this is likely meant as a shortsighted compensation.

Comment: A 5' step is not a free action. Also, the SRD say's that if you have more than one attack, you must take a full attack action. It never says you can't do a full attack action with only one.

Answer (score 2):

**The first attack does not require a Full Round action**

Please see the following from PFSRD:

> If you get more than one attack per round because your base attack bonus is high enough (see Base Attack Bonus in Classes), because you fight with two weapons or a double weapon, or for some special reason, you must use a full-round action to get your additional attacks.

Also...

> After your first attack, you can decide to take a move action instead of making your remaining attacks

Thus, your first attack is always considered a standard action, no matter what your maximum number of attacks are from all sources.  There is a note saying that as long as you have at least a standard action you may consume it with a full round one but that's for non attack related options.  So given the rules above, you're not cornered into a full attack at low levels.

Edit: A Charge attack is a Full-Round action but without examining each special ability (maybe you have a character in mind?) there is nothing else.

> Charging is a special full-round action that allows you to move up to twice your speed and attack during the action. Charging, however, carries tight restrictions on how you can move.

Comment: A Charge is a totally different action type to Full Attack - see Actions In Combat in the Combat chapter.

Comment: A charge is not a full attack. However there are full attack actions that are not simply using all your attacks (including bonus attacks like TWF). Both Lunge and Whirlwind Attack count as Full Attack actions. For example, if you had haste, you would get another attack in addition to the two special ones.
As I said above, you can choose to make the first attack as part of a full attack; you don't have to wait. One such reason is to get an AC bonus from Swordlord against a readied action.

Comment: Edited to show I didn't call a charge a full *attack* but a *full round action*.  Although +1 to you Jon Claus for the rest of the comment.

Answer (score 1):

If you only have one attack (which is not the same thing as having only one BAB), then as far as I'm aware, there is no need to use the Full Attack action at all, because you would get the same number of attacks either way.

I suppose you *could* declare a full attack, even if that only meant attacking once. I can't think of any reason to do so; not within the basics of combat, anyway. But if some effect were to depend on using one specific type of attack (or action?) versus the other, then I'd let the player pick.